# Positioning SVG elements with CSS. Having some problems

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, d3.js

Ive added 20 SVG squares to a trend graph I made using D3.js. Ech square is a clickable object which toggles lines on and off the graph. In Firefox the squares appear in the right lace, in Chrome, the CSS apparently stops working completely and the squares just drop to the bottom of the page.

Heres a link to the graph, http://www.andkensol.com/dataviz/TrendGraph/trendMov.html

And here is some of the JavaScript and CSS I used to make and then position the squares. Using position:relative is probably the cause. Would anyone have any advice or suggestions?

```
    //JS
    //AVENGERS CONTROLS 
    d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
        .attr("class", "AvengeDot")
     .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        nameInfo.transition()
            .duration(100)
            .style("opacity", .9);
        nameInfo.html("Marvel's The Avengers")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px");
        })
     .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        nameInfo.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 0);
        })


    //HUNGER GAMES CONTROLS 
    d3.select(".chart").append("svg")
        .attr("class", "HungerDot")
     .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        nameInfo.transition()
            .duration(100)
            .style("opacity", .9);
        nameInfo.html("Hunger Games")
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 10) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 30) + "px");
        })
     .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        nameInfo.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 0);
        })


           //CSS
            .AvengeDot{
            position:relative;
            left:77%;
            bottom:118%;
            width:15px;
            height:15px;
            background-color:#FF9604;
            cursor:pointer;
        }

            .HungerDot{
            position:relative;
            left:75.5%;
            bottom:114%;
            width:15px;
            height:15px;
            background-color:#FF9F18;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with D3.js, but have you tried making the SVG (or a similar one) by hand and seeing if you still have the same styling problem?  Alternatively, can you post the parsed SVG code you get after the script runs?  It should appear in Chrome or FireFox's web inspector (Firebug on older versions of FireFox).

Comment: try to define "left" and "bottom" properties in pixels

Comment: Cheers claustrofob, that seems to be working!! Just gonna have to reposition them all now...

Comment: You might want to look into using the rect element, within your svg chart rather than individually placed svg objects: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG/Element/rect